# use SQL Workbench import csv file to AWS Redshift Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I'm look for a manual and automatic way to use SQL Workbench to import/load a LOCAL csv file to a AWS Redshift database.

The manual way could be a way that click a navigation bar and select a option.

The automatic way could be some query codes to load the data, just run it.

here's my attempt:
there's an error "my target table in AWS is not found." but I'm sure the table exists, anyone know why?

```
WbImport -type=text
-file ='C:\myfile.csv'
-delimiter = ,
-table = public.data_table_in_AWS
-quoteChar=^
-continueOnError=true
-multiLine=true
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, and my google-fuu is lying to me, SQL Workbench is a MySQL tool; so why have you tagged SQL Server?

Comment: i think you mean sql/workbenchj which is the open source tool that aws recommend when using redshift - NOT the same as AQL workbench. please update your question accordingly. also remove sql-server tag.

Comment: Side-note: If you are loading a substantial amount of data, it is recommended that you use the `COPY` command to load data into Amazon Redshift.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein do you have some sample code for reference?

Comment: [Using the COPY Command to Load from Amazon S3 - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the csv file locates in my local PC, I wonder a direct way to COPY it from local to AWS, I add my answer below, but AWS said my target table in AWS is not found.

Comment: You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to copy files to Amazon S3. Look at the `aws s3 cp` command.

Comment: Did you try `public."data_table_in_AWS"`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wbimport in SQL Workbench/J to import data

For more info : http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-import.html

Like it was mentioned in the comments `COPY` command provided by Redshift is the optimal solution. You can use copy from S3, EC2 etc. 
S3 Example:

```
copy <your_table>
from 's3://<bucket>/<file>'
access_key_id 'XXXX'
secret_access_key 'XXXX'
region '<your_region>'
delimiter '\t';
```

For more examples:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html

Comment: can you post some sample code that fit my case? the documentation is confusing to me.

Comment: I post my answer below with an error, please advise